# How to uv texture with mirror modifier

Tags: modifiers, uv, image

I have mirror mesh, i want to apply a logo on it. why its repeating i dont want to apply mirror modifier. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the *Mirror* modifier and have the logo correctly displayed, enable the modifier's *Flip* option. To make sure that the logo won't repeat, enable the *Image Texture*'s *Extend* option instead of *Repeat*.

[image]